# Pandas groupby on the first n rows only for each row

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a table where each row represents the score at a certain competition of a certain competitor.

```
Name  Score    Date
A     625.0    2014-01-11
A     240.0    2014-01-11
A     590.0    2019-04-06
B     600.0    2016-04-02
B     437.5    2018-02-24
B     445.0    2019-02-09
B     417.5    2015-09-12
```

I want to add a `mean_score_last_k_competitions` to this columns, as follows

```
Name  Score    Date        mean_score_last_k_competitions
A     625.0    2014-01-21  240
A     240.0    2014-01-11  NaN
A     590.0    2019-04-06  432.5
B     600.0    2016-04-02  417.5
B     437.5    2018-02-24  509
B     445.0    2019-02-09  485
B     417.5    2015-09-12  NaN
```

(For example, for k = 3, 485 is calculated as (600 + 437.5 + 417.5)/3)

I can get the first rows `first_k = df.sort_values(by = ['Name', 'Date']).groupby('Name').head(k)`. If I aggregate `first_k` I can get 240 and 485, but I need to fill the value for all rows.

How do I solve this task using pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])
df = df.sort_values(by="Date")
df["mean_score_last_k_competitions"] = df.groupby("Name")["Score"].transform(
    lambda x: x.shift(1).rolling(3, min_periods=1).mean()
)
print(df.sort_index())
```

Prints:

```
  Name  Score       Date  mean_score_last_k_competitions
0    A  625.0 2014-01-21                          240.00
1    A  240.0 2014-01-11                             NaN
2    A  590.0 2019-04-06                          432.50
3    B  600.0 2016-04-02                          417.50
4    B  437.5 2018-02-24                          508.75
5    B  445.0 2019-02-09                          485.00
6    B  417.5 2015-09-12                             NaN
```

Comment: This is the solution I was looking for. I have never used shift and rolling before, but they seem very useful, although they seem to be quite slow. Thanks!